# Is it possible to attach a gesture recognizer to a button, so that the user swipes up after/during the button press?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I read through a few similar questions here, but most of them are for much older versions of Swift.

This tutorial shows how to create a gesture recognizer and works pretty well: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swipe-gesture-ios-tutorial-ios11

What I'd like to accomplish is to add functionality that would allow the user to swipe up or down after pressing a button, while still holding the button, and have my app react to the combination of the specific button being pressed and the upward or downward swipe gesture.

Here's the specific design I'm trying to implement. Basically I'd like the user to press the "A" button and then swipe up or down to get the "#" or "b".

[image: visual example]

Is this possible? The # & b could be image views or buttons (though if they're buttons, I don't want them to be pressable on their own). If this is a crazy design, I welcome suggestions for improvement.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/gestures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer (probably in conjunction with image views). It has the advantage that *first* it recognizes a finger held down in one spot (the "A") and *then* it tracks the movement of that finger (panning up to the sharp or down to the flat). Where the finger is held down — i.e., is it in the "A" or not — will determine whether to recognize in the first place. Then if you do recognize, you watch where the finger goes and decide whether it has entered the sharp or the flat.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a Pan Gesture Recognizer, and it worked out really well! I am simply using the y coordinate of the pan gesture to determine if the user is moving his/her finger up to the sharp or down to the flat.